# Is there a vector math version for the "power" math node?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

Does anyone know if there is a vector math version for the math node `Power`?

I am confused why the vector math node and the math node do not have the same operations.

[image]

Comment: Short answer: No, Long answer: No there isn't

Comment: It is still a mistery to me why Blender has so many math operation which require workarounds to do. For example in the compositor there isn't even a vector math node.

Comment: @tempdev nova haha ok thanks I guess I'll have to separate it with a separate XYZ node then do the math operations separately and combine it again with a combine XYZ node

Answer (score 3):

Ok so this wasn't the answer I was looking for but it works[image]

Comment: Curious... when would you use an element-wise _Power_ function?

Comment: I'm deforming a curve on all axis to simulate wind. putting a spline factor into the base slot of the power node locks the bottom of the curve to the ground and the exponent controls the stiffness of this (on different axis as I want it)